# Django request.user.userprofile.save() not working

Tags: django, savechanges

I suppose to save user's avatar and contact. When I create a form of `userprofile` and update model with `request.user.userprofile.save()`, it turns out that nothing changed in database.

I've tried many ways, including ModelForm, but I think it has nothing to do with the form, cuz when I directly using UserProfile.objects.filter(id=123).update(avatar=my_avatar) in view, no error raised but still nothing changed in database.

It's very strange that when I debug it, slow the program down, it worked!
Other models works just fine.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)

class PostUpdateUserProfileView(View):

    @method_decorator(mobile_login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PostUpdateUserProfileView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request):
        request.user.userprofile.contact = 'test'
        request.user.userprofile.save(using='master')

# DB SETTINGS
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "db",
        "USER": "<SAME_USR>",
        "PASSWORD": "<SAME_PWD>",
        "HOST": "<SAME_HOST>",
        "PORT": "3306",
        "OPTIONS": {
            'init_command': "SET default_storage_engine=INNODB, sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
    },
    "master": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "db",
        "USER": "<SAME_USR>",
        "PASSWORD": "<SAME_PWD>",
        "HOST": "<SAME_HOST>",
        "PORT": "3306",
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET default_storage_engine=INNODB, sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
    }
}
```

I thought this error might have sth to do with autocommit.

Comment: looks like you are using multiple dbs may this issue have to do something with this.

Comment: not really. I'm in development env, all the db point to the same one.

Comment: Please share DATABASE settings after removing host,username and password